Persist Microsoft Edge WebView2 states
How can I persist the state of the WebView2 using WinUI? On Android they have those saveState and restoreState methods for instance.
Basically I want to save the state of the WebView2 to be able to restore it next time the user starts the application.
I went through the APIs but did not find anything that would let you do that. It's a pity cause being able to resume where you left off after restarting your app is an essential functionality and apparently missing from WebView2. Hopefully I just missed it somehow.
I've posted the same question on GitHub but there is very little activity there so I thought to try my luck on SO.

Save the entire state as in if you were, say, typing something in a form field in that web view, you should be able to close the app, reopen it, and the text should be there..?

Ideally yes, but most of all the current page and scroll position and the page history, back and forward stack if you want.

being able to resume where you left off after restarting your app is an essential functionality:  How does this relate to WebView2? I can't remember the last time I visited a website and wanted to save the state so I could pick up where I left off. Job application sties may have such functionality, but it's not functionality of the browser. Also, WebView was the predecessor to WebView2 and is quite different than WebView2. Please use clear and concise language and don't make up your own terminology.

Say I wanted to implement a web browser with WebView2 and want to persist multiple tabs with their history and current position.

Then you should probably forget about WebView2, hire a team of developers and create your own control.

So you are saying this is not doable with WebView2 as it is then. That's what I feared. Definitely a major oversight from Microsoft. I mean persistence is the basic of any software. Not being able to do that properly is very limiting to say the least. In my case that's more a showstopper really.

persistence is the basic of any software: Not necessarily. It depends on the purpose of the software.

It seems that you may not understand what WebView2 is. You may consider conducting some more research.
